# How to inject html code by angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi i'm trying to inject html code into a table it works good but the problem is there are some functions do not fired when i click on them i dont know why, can any one help??
heres the function:

```
storyboard.getTmeLineTopDataKm= function (deviceId) {

        var url = servername+'api/position/timeLineTopKm/'+deviceId;

        console.log("Inside getMaxChaufeeurId " + url);


        function onSuccess(response) {
            console.log("+++++getMaxChaufeeurId SUCCESS++++++");

            if (response.data.success != false) {
              //alert(JSON.stringify(response.data));
              $scope.km=response.data.km;
              $scope.km2=response.data.km;
              //alert(deviceId);
                             var elm=angular.element(document.querySelector('#ysf_'+deviceId));
                             elm.append('<div style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:10px;"">'                      
                            +'<i ng-click="storyboard.getLastDayTimeLine()" style="cursor: pointer;padding-right:23px" class="fa fa-arrow-left " aria-hidden="true"></i>{{currentDatee}}'
                            +'<i style=" cursor: pointer;padding-left:23px" ng-click="storyboard.getForwardDayTimeLine()" class="fa fa-arrow-right " aria-hidden="true"></i> <br/>  '                      
                            +'<i class="fa fa-road" aria-hidden="true" >'+ $scope.km2 +'Km'+'</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                            +'<i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true">' + $scope.speed2 +'km/h'+'</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                            +'<i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:green"  aria-hidden="true">  01:17</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                            +'<i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:red" style="padding:150px" aria-hidden="true">  00:19</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                            +'<i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:orange" style="padding-right:160px" aria-hidden="true"> 02:51</i>'

                            +'</div>'
                            + '<div style="margin-top:7px;margin-left:10px;position:relative;"  id="visualization2_'+deviceId+'"></div>'
                            );

             // alert( $scope.km2);






             //$scope.MyData=response.data;
            }
        };

        function onError(response) {
            console.log("-------getMaxChaufeeurId FAILED-------");

            console.log(response.data);
            console.log("Inside getMaxChaufeeurId error condition...");
        };

        //----MAKE AJAX REQUEST CALL to GET DATA----
        ajaxServicess.getData(url, 'GET', '').then(onSuccess, onError);

    };
```

For exemple this function  ng-click="storyboard.getLastDayTimeLine()" does not work.

```
 <table width="100%">
                      <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
                        <tr>
                          <td  style="width: 30px;"></td>
                           <td><p>Name</p></td>
                        <td><p>ID</p></td>
                        <td><p>GPS date</p></td>
                        <td><p>Adresse</p></td>
                        <td><p>Company</p></td>
                        </tr>  
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat-start="device in MyDeviceObject">
                          <td>
                            <button  ng-if="device.expanded" ng-click="device.expanded = false">-</button>
                            <button ng-click="storyboard.getSelectedRow(device);device.expanded = true" ng-if="!device.expanded" >+</button>
                          </td>
                          <td><p>{{device.name}}</p></td>
                          <td><p>{{device.uniqueid}}</p></td>
                          <td><p>{{device.devicetime}}</p></td>
                          <td><p>{{device.adress}}</p></td>
                          <td><p>{{device.company}}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr  ng-if="device.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
                          <td></td>
                          <td  colspan="5" id="ysf_{{device.id}}" >

                          </div>

                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table>
```

Comment: Why don't you add this HTML in your .html file ? Use `ng-if` or `ng-show` to hide and show when needed

Comment: you will have to `$comple` it

Comment: can you explain your idea please??

Comment: Weedoze its a dynamique content i had to do that theres no choice

Answer (score 0):

Once you bind html from js you need to re compile it in order fully render the html DOM

Add this directive to your `querySelector` element as attribute . This will recompile the DOM

```
.directive('bindHtmlCompile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.bindHtmlCompile);
                }, function (value) {
                    element.html(value);
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: how to add bindHtmlCompile to querySelector??

Comment: no no assign this as attribute to the element from html file

Comment: post the html file

Comment: `<td  colspan="5" id="ysf_{{device.id}}"  bind-html-compile >`

Comment: i did but the function does not fired

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: it will take long time to do that...i can give any thing you need..just ask

Comment: @abdellatifzoumhane it'll take a long time for us if you don't provide us a plnkr ;-).